# Converting value from percentage to opacity

Tags: wpf, xaml, slider

I have a slider that controls the opacity of image.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="0.60*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="0.40*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Column="1"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="1">
      <Image Opacity="{Binding Path=Value,
                               ElementName=fadeSlider,
                               Mode=Default,
                               UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             Source="/Mydll;component/Images/Preview.png"
             Stretch="Fill" />
    </Border>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsChecked,
                              ElementName=applyTransparency,
                              Mode=Default}">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.70*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.30*" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <telerik:RadSlider x:Name="fadeSlider"
                         Grid.Column="0"
                         Width="130"
                         IsMoveToPointEnabled="True"
                         LargeChange="10"
                         Maximum="100"
                         Minimum="0"
                         SmallChange="5"
                         ThumbVisibility="Visible"
                         TickFrequency="25"
                         TickPlacement="BottomRight"
                         Value="1">
        <telerik:RadSlider.TickTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
              <TextBlock FontSize="11"
                         Text="{Binding}" />
            </Grid>
          </DataTemplate>
        </telerik:RadSlider.TickTemplate>
      </telerik:RadSlider>
      <telerik:RadMaskedNumericInput Grid.Column="1"
                                     Width="25"
                                     Margin="2"
                                     MaskedInput:MaskedInputExtensions.Maximum="100"
                                     MaskedInput:MaskedInputExtensions.Minimum="0"
                                     Text="{Binding Path=Value,
                                                    ElementName=fadeSlider,
                                                    Mode=TwoWay}" />

    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

The issue is slider works from 0-100 and opacity works from 0-1 how should I bind the slider value to image's opacity. Slider value 0 represents 1 opacity and Slider value 100 represents 0 opacity.

Comment: You need to write [`Converter`](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/15/so-what-s-a-silverlight-value-converter-anyway.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write a [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) for that. Like:

```
public class OpacityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
           object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int sliderValue = System.Convert.ToInt32(value);

        return (100 - sliderValue)/100d;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
           object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Grid.Resources>
      <myNamespace:OpacityConverter x:Key="opacityConverter"/>
</Grid.Resources>

<Image Opacity="{Binding Path=Value,
           ElementName=fadeSlider,
           Mode=Default,
           UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged},
           Converter={StaticResource opacityConverter}"                            
        Source="/Mydll;component/Images/Preview.png"
        Stretch="Fill" />
```